# WP8 Databind button click/Command with RoutedEventHandler

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Fairly new to Windows Phone and Xaml and I decided to start using the DataTemplates as it looked neater and I could easily switch them etc.

I have a requirement where on a button click depending on the data on the item in the list I want to call a different function or with different parameters.  I thought the easiest way would be to bind a RoutedEventHandler to it via an anonymous function.

When I did this in code-behind with static controls on the formed it worked perfectly.  It also worked when I added my own controls to a stack panel etc.  But it was all quite messy.

```
// Example of RoutedEventHandler that works when I create the button in code behind
model.clickEventHandler = (s, e) => LoadResult(r.id);

 <ScrollViewer Name="scrvResults" >
        <ListBox Name="lbResults" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                             <Button Command="{Binding clickEventHandler}"  > 
                                   // Stuff
                                   // Doesn't crash but doesn't fire the event
                             </Button>
                             <Button Click="{Binding clickEventHandler}"  > 
                                   // Stuff
                                   // Throws a com exception
                             </Button>
                      </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I've tried various sub options.  All the examples i've seen seem to link to a static function.  Is this just some syntax i'm getting wrong is can I not bind to it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your command to a type of ICommand.  See here for more info:

[ICommand interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand.aspx)

[Command Binding](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/command-binding/)

Button click event can be bound by using interaction triggers, not by simply binding the event to the click attribute:

[Using EventTrigger in XAML for MVVM – No Code Behind Code](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/using-eventtrigger-in-xaml-for-mvvm-no.html)